# co-channel interference

Tags: matlab

Please can someone help me write a Matlab code that expresses the interference shown in the image.What is the formula for the interference in this case and how is it calculated?
The received signal of the first received antennas can be explained:
r1 = h11 x1+ h21x2 + v1
where h11  denotes the channel between T1T1 and R1 , h21 denotes the channel between T2 and R1 , x1 is the signal transmitted from T1 and x2 is the signal transmitted from T2, and v1 the AWGN on the R1.
h21 x2 will be considered as an interference in the first receive antenna.
How is this represented for multiple antennas? How are variables expressed in MATLAB? For example how . is determined h11, x1, v1 ect.

[image: What is the formula for the interference in this case and how is it calculated?]

Comment: Hello! And welcome. For homework/test type questions, you need to let us know how far in your reasoning you are, and where you're stuck. As is, I doubt your question will be answered...

Comment: You'll need to _edit your question_ with more detail, and expect that we'll help you with formulating the math, but that we'll expect _you_ to actually write the code.  Details to add are things like what the service is, how the interfering towers are located, and how the interfering signals are distinguished from the intended one (i.e., is it CDMA, FDMA, TDMA, or some combination).

Comment: @TimWescott i did

Comment: @Jdip hello, I edited

Comment: Hi Mary, "how are variables expressed in matlab", how do I calculate products in matlab and so on: Really not signal processing questions. Matlab comes with a big help with a good, built-in tutorial that takes not long to do. We can't explain it any better than the actual people that developed matlab. Sadly, there's no shortcut to learning how to program in a language if you need to program in a language, sorry.